# Why does my plugin have the Scala version in its folder structure?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have the following in my build.sbt file:

```
name := "my-plugin"

organization := "com.mysite"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

publishMavenStyle := true

publishArtifact in Test := false

pomIncludeRepository := { x => false }

publishTo <<= (version) { version: String =>
  val nexus = "https://oss.sonatype.org/"
  if (version.trim.endsWith("SNAPSHOT")) Some("snapshots" at nexus + "content/repositories/snapshots")
  else                                   Some("releases" at nexus + "service/local/staging/deploy/maven2")
}
```

When I go to publish the plugin using `sbt publish` I get the following output:

```
published my-plugin to https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/mysite/my-plugin_2.10_0.13/1.0-SNAPSHOT/my-plugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Could someone tell me why it's being published with the Scala version number in the directory structure, and is it supposed to? Is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is normal.

Sbt plugins must be compiled against specific version of sbt and a specific version of Scala (for sbt 0.13.5 it is scala 2.10.4), as [documented in the official documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Extending/Plugins.html#id1).

You can see that in your path: `my-plugin_2.10_0.13`, the scala version is `2.10.x` and sbt is `0.13.x`.

By the way you may also want to take a look at [cross build](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Cross-Build.html#introduction) documentation.

Comment: I just realised it's not an SBT plugin I'm developing and that line shouldn't have been in there. It's just a module for the Play Framework. Does what you said apply to other libraries as well?

Comment: In general yes (read cross build link I've posted). However if it's not a plugin sbt version should not be a part of path. But if you remove `sbtPlugin := true`, it should be gone.